# DropDownListFor problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if anyone has ever experienced a problem like I'm currently having.

Controller:

```
_OpsAdminViewModel.userRoleID = _OpsAdminViewModel.retrieveHighestUserRoleGuidFromUserID(id.Value);
_OpsAdminViewModel.ActiveRoleList = _OpsAdminViewModel.GetActiveRoles();
_OpsAdminViewModel.UserRoleSelectList = new SelectList(_OpsAdminViewModel.ActiveRoleList, "RoleID", "RoleName", _OpsAdminViewModel.userRoleID);
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.selectedRoleID, Model.UserRoleSelectList)
```

Now, here is where it gets very odd.  When I place a break on the Controller's Return line or the View's DropDownListFor line, I literally see that the value I want to have selected should be selected.  Expanding the UserRoleSelectList object, reveals the correct "SelectedValue" ID and in the "Results View", the correct value has a "True" for selected.  However, when the page is rendered, the pull-down menu is displaying the 0-position element of the pull-down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model binding works by binding to the value of your property. When your use `DropDownListFor()` the method internally builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `Selected` property based on the value of your property. In your case, the value of `selectedRoleID` does not match the value of one of the options so the first option is selected (because something has to be).

Set the value of `selectedRoleID` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view

```
model.selectedRoleID = _OpsAdminViewModel.userRoleID;
return View(model);
```

and delete the last parameter in your `SelectList` constructor since its pointless.

Comment: THAT WAS EASY!!!  I complicated things by having two different properties in my view model (userRoleID and selectedRoleID).  It is fixed now.  THANK YOU!!!